# Why Laravel Request object is replacing spaces with underscores on my form names?

Tags: forms, laravel, post

I have a Form posting variables containing spaces in their names

e.g.

I perform my ajax request and i can see in chrome inspector that name is correctly passed "with blank space)

In my api.php:

```
Route::post('/user', 'UserController@get');
```

UserController

```
function get(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->input('Name Surname')); //display null
    dd($request->all()); //I notice the key's changed to Name_Surname

}
```

Taken that I can't change the names because they have to contain spaces (bad practice? ok but it has to be like that):

how can I avoid spaces to be replaced?
(maybe without to have to manipulate the request->all() returned array keys by hand....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer I don't believe there to be such a way.

You can map the response with a bit of string replace though:

```
$data = $request->all()->mapWithKeys(function($item, $key) {
    return [str_replace("_", " ", $key) => $item];
});
```

If it's something you want to apply across the board, you could possible rig up some middleware to apply it to all requests.

Answer (score 2):

If previous answer not work for you, try this:

```
$data = collect($request->all())->mapWithKeys(function($item, $key) {
            return [str_replace("_", " ", $key) => $item];
        })->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also normalize the Input Name if it is known...

```
$field_name = 'FIELD NAME WITH SPACES';
$value = request( str_replace( ' ', '_', $field_name ) );
```